# JS не находит картинку для backgroundImage

Tags: javascript

Проблема заключается в том, что как только я вкладываю картинку в папку `JS` ее не видит. Проще говоря так работает:

```
<script>
     choose_type_5.onclick = function() {
     choose_type_5.style.background="red";
     choose_type_1.style.background="white";
     choose_type_2.style.background="white";
     choose_type_3.style.background="white";
     choose_type_4.style.background="white";
     IdMaket.style.backgroundImage="url('15.jpg')";

   };
</script>
```

А вот так когда задаю:

```
<script>
     choose_type_1.onclick = function() {
     choose_type_1.style.background="red";
     choose_type_2.style.background="white";
     choose_type_3.style.background="white";
     choose_type_4.style.background="white";
     choose_type_5.style.background="white";
     IdMaket.style.backgroundImage="url('../images/halat/halat-white.jpg')";

   };
</script>
```

Выдает GET:

> file:///D:/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/images/halat/IMG_7500.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Вам нужен веб-сервер

Comment: Или можно попробовать запустить браузер с выключенным сандбокс режимом. Например можно запустить хром с ярлыка с параметром --no-sandbox

Comment: а вас не смущает, что картинку вы пишите `halat-white.jpg` а в ошибке ругается на `img_7500.jpg` ?

Comment: Директории: `../images/` - уровень выше, `./` - текущая, `./images/` - вложенная.

Answer (score 1):

При задании ссылки на изображение в свойстве `background-image` через `js`, `url` лучше указывать относительно текущего документа:

```
// Директория расположения изображения уровнем выше.
element.style.backgroundImage = "url('../images/image.jpg')";

// Документ и изображение расположены в одной директории.
element.style.backgroundImage = "url('image.jpg')";

// Изображение расположено во вложенной директории.
element.style.backgroundImage = "url('./images/image.jpg')";
```